# Magento returns 404 after switching language on SOME product pages

Tags: magento-1.8, product, url, 404

I have problem with a Magento site I haven't been able to solve Googling my way around. On I have 3 store views (NL, EN, DE). When on a product page and I want to switch language sometimes I get a 404 error but other times the product switches correctly to the right language. I have observed the URL behavior closely and came up with this:

In case of a successful switch the URL changes from for example www.example.com/supplies_nl/product.html to www.example.com/supplies_en/product.html?___from_store=supplies_en

However in other cases when the switch in unsuccessful the URL is changed from
www.example.com/supplies_nl/product.html to www.example.com/supplies_nl/product.html?___from_store=supplies_en resulting in a 404 error.

Has anyone encountered such behavior and what can be done to have this working correctly al the time?

Using Magento 1.8.0

Comment: This can't be right. In your first example it should be ___from_store=supplies_nl  and in your second ___from_store=supplies_en plus in your second example clearly there is no storeview change

Comment: Exactly, that is the funny thing. Some products have a store view change and some don't. Could it be something on the product level that needs adjusting?

Comment: Any Full Page Cache in the mix here and if so, did you holepunch the store switcher?

Comment: I cleaned all cache so that won't contribute to the problem. What do you mean by holepunching the store switcher?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on my page by just adding the store where the link should go to then end of the url, like:
www.example.com/supplies_nl/product.html to www.example.com/supplies_nl/product.html?___store=english
Then it directs to the correct store